# Load UML Model with EMF that has an applied profile

Tags: eclipse, uml, profile, eclipse-emf

I am trying to load a UML model stored as XMI via the eclipse MDT/UML2 implementation.

So far I have successfully loaded the model itself from a `ResourceSet` and I can walk through my model as expected. However, I have trouble loading our custom UML profile that is contained in the XMI file.

I have `xmlns:MyProfile="..."` and `xsi:schemaLocation="... file:/path/to/profile.uml"` attributes in the XMI file, as well as a `profileApplication` tag  inside the `uml:Model` tag.

However, on the loaded model calls to `getAppliedProfiles` and `getProfileApplications` return an empty list. When using the debugging I can see that the model is not loading the `profileApplication` tag correctly.

I experimented with various ways to configure the UriMap of the ResourceSet, but so far haven't managed to get anything working. When I open the corresponding XMI file within eclipse, everything is showing up fine and the profile is loaded well, so all paths are correct. What else am I missing?

Comment: Which program wrote the xmi you are trying to read? It's not created by eclipse MDT, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not load profiles because the profile is related to a project property and can not be used outside as a standalone. You can load a model then take a profile and apply this profile as a project property. It would do the job.
Hope this help.

Comment: Apparently something was wrong in the loading code. After fixing that the applied profile was initialized correctly as well.

Comment: Thx for the info because I was convinced it could not work !!

Comment: Sorry, it belongs to the customer, but I did nothing different from the samples you can find around on the net. You just have to be very careful that everything matches together (so copy-paste from samples usually will not work.)